# Is the viability of a limited supply currency dependent on the equality or inequality of its distribution among potential users?

Tags: financial-economics, money, cryptocurrency

Presumably, the more unequal the distribution of a limited supply currency among potential users, the more advantage early accumulators have vs latecomers; as soon as the early accumulators begin to spend the currency, they will bid up prices in the currency to become unattractive to new users of it.

Is such a limited supply currency, that experiences a lot of speculative hoarding, not destined to -- if nothing else -- be replaced by a similar such currency (technically similar), that's more equally distributed from the outset?

Is this not of massive consequence for e.g. bitcoin, being hoarded the way it is?

**Edit:**

I'll give an example if that helps clarify my question: Peter, Paul and Bob have set up their own homesteads on different places on a desolate island where they've been stranded after a ship wreck. On the island there is a limited supply of two kinds of nice looking seashells; call them type A and B. Type A might be trifle prettier than B but other than that they are similar in size and quantity.

The guys haven't yet begun to trade, but they know of each other and anticipate future trade. Because of this Peter has gathered all the A-seashells that he could find, speculating in their future use as a currency. Paul and Bob have also collected some A-seashells, but much fewer.

The first part of my question, translated to the specifics of this example would be: Given the unequal distribution of the A-shells as a potential currency, is there any reason to why those would be used, to the obvious unfair advantage of Peter, instead of using either credit money (IOU:s) or type B-shells (should they distrust fiat money...), that they would all have a chance to collect in equal amounts before they begin to trade?

But the second and main part of the question is (presuming "no" as answer to the first part): Is not this use-disincentivizing effect, of hoarding tokens prior to any wide-spread adoption, of vital importance when deciding the future value of a limited supply, hoarded token such as bitcoin?

I realize the questions may seem kind of leading, but i'd be interested in any and all motivations as to agreement/disagreement.

Comment: there's a seed of a question here but I don't entirely understand what the question is. I think the scenario needs to be better specified.